# Troubles with python requests lib and redirect in Flask

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I try to create a service with Flask that has two functions: 1) Send post request (with python requests lib) with credentials for login on the forum; 2) After success login to open another page from this forum with Flask redirect method.

The code looks as:

```
@app.route("/protected_area")
@login_is_required
def protected_area():

    session = requests.Session()

    user = fake_useragent.UserAgent().random

    header = CaseInsensitiveDict()
    header['user-agent'] = user

    payload = {
        'mode': MODE,
        'username': LOGIN,
        'password': PASS
    }

    print(payload)

    url_main = BASIC_SITE_URL + 'login'
    url_login = BASIC_SITE_URL + 'login/form'
    url_cabinet = BASIC_SITE_URL + '?perspective=pa-home'

    response = session.get(url_main, headers=header, allow_redirects=False)

    cookies = get_cookies(response.cookies, "tm.domain.com")
    print('cookies_1:', cookies)

    cookies = cookies.split(';')
    print('cookies_2:', cookies)

    cookies = [(c.split('=', 1)) for c in cookies]
    print('cookies_3:', cookies)

    session.cookies.update(dict(cookies))
    print('session.cookies:', session.cookies.update(dict(cookies)))
    print('dict_cookies:', dict(cookies))

    response = session.post(url_login, data=payload, cookies=dict(cookies), headers=header, allow_redirects=False)
    print('response:', response)
    print(response.text)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        print('Sucessful!')
        return redirect(url_cabinet)

    elif response.status_code == 404:
        print('Unsuccessful!')
        return redirect(url_main)
```

But it doesn't work: I don't know how to send session/headers to open the page with redirect - this page opens as an unauthorized user.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're printing out individual cookies and then re-wrapping cookies in another dict? It should be as simple as passing the response cookies to the next request:

```
    ...
    response = session.get(url_main, headers=header, allow_redirects=False)
    ...
    ...
    next_response =  response = session.post(url_login, data=payload, cookies=response.cookies, headers=header, allow_redirects=False)
    ...
    ...
```